# tomcat 5.5 startup script on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, tomcat5.5

Can any one share their Tomcat startup script 
I am looking for a tomcat start up script on a Ubuntu machine.
My Ubuntu is 10.04 server.
The tomcat is 5.5.30.

It is in /opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.31

I tried a script

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# tomcat
#
# chkconfig:
# description: Start up the Tomcat servlet engine.

# Source function library.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions


RETVAL=$?
CATALINA_HOME="/opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.31"

case "$1" in
start)
if [ -f $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh ];
then
echo $"Starting Tomcat"
/opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.31/bin/startup.sh

fi
;;
stop)
if [ -f $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh ];
then
echo $"Stopping Tomcat"
/opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.31/bin/shutdown.sh
fi
;;
*)
echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
exit 1
;;
esac
exit $RETVAL
```

but it did not worked after a reboot.
But the same script works if I do `/etc/init.d/tomcat start`
or `/etc/init.d/tomcat stop`
I have done
`update-rc.d tomcat defaults`
as it is a Ubuntu server but on reboot all of this fails to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some weired reason the script was not working after reboot and it turns out that Tomcat needs JAVA_HOME variable to be able to start itself.This variable I had defined in .bashrc but this script was still not able to work.So when I defined JAVA_HOME in the above script also then it did worked.

Answer (score 0):

To start a service on boot, the init script should be in the directory `/etc/init.d`, but the real start and stop are triggered by the symbolic links in the directories /etc/rcX.d (X being the *[runlevel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel) number*).

On Debian derivatives like Ubuntu, when your init script is in `/etc/init.d`, you can use `update-rc.d` to create the links, for example if your init script is called tomcat :

```
update-rc.d tomcat default
```